# Is there a text to numeric conversion done here?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, types, decimal

I have a table that has a column `amount` of type `DEC`.
The following queries work:
`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE amount < '1';`

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE amount = '1.5';`

I.e. even though I use quotes like the `amount` is for character values (despite them actual being numeric) the queries still work.

My question is:
Is this because the SQL Server "understands" that the data type is actually a number and ignores the quotes when executing the sql `select`
OR
the SQL server first converts the `amount` value to text and then does the comparison?So this has a performance overhead due to conversion?

Comment: SQL understands that `amount` is a number from the design of the table and seeks a numeric value in the '1' without bothering to "understand" whether it is convertible or it is not.

Comment: @enb081:What does the `seeks a numeric value in the '1'` mean?Doesn't this imply conversion?

Comment: MySQL coerces the given value to the same type as your column.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is  a numerical conversion happening, since the column 'amount' is defined as numerical. To test this, you can try:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE amount < '1a';
```

you will get the error message:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

meaning that varchar is being converted to numeric and not the other way round.

Comment: The error message you posted is from Microsoft SQL Server. The question is tagged MySQL.

Comment: Because running such a test in a different RDBMS is pointless and doesn't answer the question. IIRC in MySQL in fact `'1a'` will be implicitly cast to `1` with the non numeric characters discarded and no error is generated.

Comment: [SQL Fiddle for MySQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6248/1). Following the logic in this answer would lead to the wrong conclusion.  No error does not mean the cast is from decimal to varchar.

Comment: I'm not the question asker.

Comment: @enb081: the DBMS involved *does* make a difference - especially if it's MySQL with it's broken type checking. Your example *should* give an error but doesn't on MySQL. If you change `<` to `=` you will atually get the row back (where `amount = 1`) which is completely wrong: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6248/4